# HTML5 file API or Java bridge to acces to local Files?

Tags: java, javascript, html5, file-systems

I've to access to files on the software user and I don't know if it's better to use a full JS app with HTML5 File Api rules or use Java and communicate with it ?

Comment: Do all of your user's browsers support the File API?

Comment: No because they don't have Chrome so no File API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the option to use the HTML file api and you are not worried about browser compatibility then you should avoid using 3rd party things like java as a far as possible and keep as close as possible to bare bones.

Java requires a JRE to be installed on the client PC, which adds a deployment layer, however simple it may be.